# Proving complex normal matrix is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}^{\mathbb{C}}$ be a normal complex matrix that satisfies $A^{9}+3A^{5}=3A^{7}+A^{3}$.

I need to prove that $A$ is self-adjoint (Hermitian)  and also $A^{2}=A^{4}$.

It's easy to see that if $p(t)=(t-1)^{3}$ then $p(A^{2})=O$.
Could it be the minimal/characteristic polynomial of $A^2$? If it is, how so?
I figure that finding the ch.polynomial of $A$ and proving that all its roots are real is sufficiant for proving this.

Comment: Since it is normal, diagonalize all those equations with a unitary transformation. Assume a unitary $U$ is such that $D=UAU^*$ for some diagonal $D$. Multiply all the equations by $U\rightarrow$ and $\leftarrow U^*$. Now they are equations for the eigenvalues. Use that the given equation is the same as $A^3(A^2-I)^3=0$. You get that the eigenvalues are either $0,\pm1$. Therefore $A^2=U^*D^2U=U^*D^4U=A^4$.

Comment: It is self-adjoin since $A^*=(U^*DU)^*=U^*D^*U=U^*DU=A$.

Comment: Yes, just permute the powers of it and its transform one factor at a time. However, that is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then
$$
\lambda^9-3\lambda^7+3\lambda^5-\lambda^3=0
$$
(why?) so
$$
\lambda^3(\lambda^2-1)^3=0
$$
Therefore all eigenvalues of $A$ are real, which is an equivalent condition for a normal matrix to be self-adjoint.

The second part uses the fact that $\lambda\in\{0,1,-1\}$ (diagonalize it).

Comment: as Hellen said, $A=Q^{*}DQ\Rightarrow D=QAQ^{*}$ for some inverse $Q$, and $D=diag(\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n})$ , but how placing $D$ in the given polynomial gives your equation for any $\lambda_{k}$?

Comment: @gbi1977 You don't need that until the second part. If $Av=\lambda v$, with $v\ne0$, then also $A^kv=\lambda^kv$. So multiply both sides of the given equation by $v$.

Comment: I think I got it, the matrix $A$ satisfies the given $p(t)$, so the minimal poly of $A$, $m(t)$, devides $p(t)$. since the roots of $m(t)$ are all of the eigenvalues of $A$, then they must also be the roots of $p(t)$, is this explaination also correct? @egreg

Comment: @gbi1977 You don't need the minimal polynomial at all: an eigenvalue $\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda^3(\lambda^2-1)^2=0$, so $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$.